# Text Selection is not working on Single Cell - ng2-table

Tags: angular, firefox, datatable, textselection

Here is Data Table for angular2, written by Valor software.

http://valor-software.com/ng2-table/

And this is Demo.

I tried to select text in single cell by mouse click and drag (**!important - inside single cell. on multiple cell is working**)
It was working on Chrome and not working on Mozila FireFox. But now its is not works on Chrome too.

Further information is below.

```
<tr *ngFor="let row of rows">
   <td (click)="cellClick(row, column.name)" *ngFor="let column of columns" [innerHtml]="sanitize(getData(row, column.name))"></td>
</tr>

public cellClick(row:any, column:any):void {
   this.cellClicked.emit({row, column});
}
```

This is the function for table cell clicked.
User mouse down, and mouse move, and finally mouseup.
At this time, this function is triggered and selection is disappearing.

Please help me to solve this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this issue by updating this part.

```
<td (click)="cellClick(row, column.name)" *ngFor="let column of columns" [innerHtml]="getData(row, column.name)"></td>
```

It was using Sanitize for building html inline code.